# PHP - Passing Array into a Function - The Purpose of Reset

Tags: php

I am going through some book examples and just can't understand why one example works the way it does. In this example an array is passed to a function. The function then creates a table containing all elements on separate lines. My question is how does reset work in this function? In my logic, when reset resets $data, the array is returned to the first element and the table should endlessly show the first element only. Just seeing the results in the browser I know this is not true. But why?

```
<?php

    function create_table($data) {
        echo "<table border=\"1\">";
        reset($data); // Remember this is used to point to the beginning 
        $value = current($data);
        while ($value) {
            echo "<tr><td>".$value."</td></tr>\n";
            $value = next($data);
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
?>

<?php
    $my_array = array('Line one. ','Line two. ','Line three. ');
    create_table($my_array);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrays have an internal pointer that indicate the current element position. The `current()` function gets the current one, and the `next()` moves to the next item and gets it. The `reset()` function moves the pointer back to the start.

Ultimately it's a waste of function calls. Just using `foreach($data as $value)` is sufficient, but there's an even easier way:

```
function create_table($data) {
  echo "<table border=\"1\"><tr><td>".implode("</td></tr><tr><td>",$data)."</td></tr></table>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reset is only called once, outside of the while loop. So it only resets the array once per call to create_table. Then, in the loop, there is next($data) which move the pointer on to the next element

Comment: Thank you!!! Very helpful. I realize my mistake now was to assume reset effects the array more than once. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll highlight the loop:

```
while ($value) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$value."</td></tr>\n";
        $value = next($data);
    }
```

Did you see the last statement? `next($array)` moves the "pointer" one forward and the value  is stored in `$value`. When the array pointer has reached the end, `next()` will return `false` and that will also stop the loop.

Constructs like `foreach()` do this implicitly, i.e. it resets the array and loops over its elements.

Comment: That's... not the question that's being asked.

Comment: @Kolink The way I see it, OP is wondering why it doesn't endlessly loop.

Answer (score 0):

> why [does this code work]?

You are iterating over the array (`$data`) using [`current()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) and [`next()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php).

#### Flow:

- `reset()` the array to the beginning
- get the `current()` element (first)
- loop `while` you have a `$value`

  - move to the `next()` element

Answer (score 0):

Because the `while` loop has a `next()` in this line `$value = next($data);` which goes to the next element in the array. Hence, the loop iterates over the array using `current()` and `next()`

Answer (score 0):

Because [`next`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) moves the internal array pointer ahead.  `reset` is used to make sure that the internal array pointer is at the start (i.e. just in case `next` or something similar was called on it before this function call), and `current` gets the first value.  Then, it continues to be moved ahead with `next`.

In actuality, since the array is not passed by reference, I'm pretty sure that `reset` does nothing, but I'm not positive.

I would not recommend this at all, and I think it's kind of antiquated; I would use `foreach`.  The above won't even work if a falsy value is legitimately inside of the array.

Comment: The last comment here is actually pretty important.  If you had `false` or `0` as an array value, your loop would bail prematurely.  Probably best to use a `foreach` or `for` looping construct here.

Answer (score 0):

`reset()` is setting the array pointer to the beginning upon entering the function to make sure that it when the array it iterated it starts at the beginning.

The `next()` inside the `while` loop actually advances the pointer.